# filter Google Custom Search api version 2 Results by Date

Tags: jquery, google-search-api

I am using google custom search on my web application (version 2) and I would like that my user's would be 
able to filter the result by two date such as 'from date' and 'to date'.
The problem is that I have no idea about how to pass two date and how to manage the search results to able to that.
How to get search results by date filter.

```
function letGoSearch() {
        $('#loader').show();
        var keyword = $('#Keyword').val();  
        var yyyy = $('#Year option:selected').val();
        var mm = $('#Month option:selected').val();
        var dd = $('#Day option:selected').val();
        var fromDate = "";
        dd = parseInt(dd, 10);
        fromDate = yyyy + mm + (pad(dd + 1, 2));

        var d = new Date();
        var month = d.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = d.getDate();
        var toDate = d.getFullYear() + (('' + month).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + month + (('' + day).length < 2 ? '0' : '') + day;

        var siteToSearch = "us.letgo.com";
        var searchtexts = document.getElementById("Keyword").value;
        var text = "";
        if ($('#searchByTitle:checked').length > 0) {

            text = "site:" + siteToSearch + " intitle:" + searchtexts;
        }
        else {
            text = "site:" + siteToSearch + " " + searchtexts;
        }
              google.search.cse.element.render({ gname: 'letgo', div: 'OutputLG', tag: 'searchresults-only',  attributes: { linkTarget: '_blank'} });

       var element = google.search.cse.element.getElement('letgo');
            element.execute(text);

    }
```

Comment: Check this https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/structured_data#page_dates